# find out the point of reflection

Tags: geometry, reflection

> Given a point $(1, -5, 6)$ is reflected about the plane having equation $-2x+7y+9z=4$. What will the point of reflection about the plane?
>
> a.) $\left(\frac{98}{67}, \frac{-389}{67}, \frac{-185}{67} \right)$
>
> b.) $\left(\frac{93}{67}, \frac{-426}{67}, \frac{285}{67} \right)$
>
> c.) $\left(\frac{-80}{67}, \frac{426}{67}, \frac{288}{67} \right)$
>
> d.) None

I know that the point of reflection will at a distance from the plane equal to distance of the point $(1, -5, 6)$ from the plane but can't proceed further.

I studied math up to 12th. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose the reflection of $A=(1, -5, 6)$ on the plane $$-2x+7y+9z = 4\tag 1$$ is 
$$A' = (1 - 4t, -5+14t, 6+18t)\tag 2.$$  then the midpoint $$(A+A')/2 = (1 - 2t, -5+7t, 6+9t) $$ must be on the plane $(1).$  therefore $t$ must satisfy 
$$-2(1-2t)+7(-5+7t)+9(6+9t) = 4\to 134 t = -7, t=-7/134.$$ now putting this value of $t$ in $(2)$ will give us the required point.

Comment: @Bhaskara-III, you are welcome.

Comment: many many thanks!